# Wagtail: How to get a table of content of a page (StreamField)

Tags: wagtail, tableofcontents, wagtail-streamfield

How can I create a table of content from my headings within a page?

I use StreamFields in my page and I would like to create a table of content based of the `<h1>`, `<h2>` and `<h3>` headings.

Comment: You could pull the headings out using `page.block_type` to check for 'h1', 'h2', etc., but I think you would need to define each heading block as a `StructBlock` to enforce entering a title for each  'h1', 'h2', etc. section - so each `StructBlock` would have a `title` and a `value` section.  The following shows how to pull things out by `block_type` in a template, but you should also be able to do this in a `views` method as well with the proper imports:  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/streamfield.html?highlight=streamfield#template-rendering

Comment: I don't have each heading within a StructBlock. I also use RichTextBlock which can have different types of headings

Comment: Your content will be stored in the database in this form:  [{"type": "block_type", "value": {"content": "<h2>Some Title</h2><p>paragraph text</p>"}, "id": "07244dd2-9a1e-40cc-8a81-2668ddb0e19a"}].  `content` is the name of the field on the `Page` model. Rethinking my first suggestion, in looking at how it's stored in the database, you could just parse the `content` field looking for the various header tags.  BeautifulSoup might help with this parsing.